# Ubuntu 18.04: How to display all non-English characters in wine?

Tags: wine, unicode

So I have a music collection that came from various places (East Asian, Indian, those European languages with accents and etc).

When I launch a Windows app like [foobar2000](https://www.foobar2000.org/) (swiss knife of sorts for music files) in Wine, I can see squares are used instead of the Japanese characters for the artist I'm looking at.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

As a test, I tried:

```
sudo apt install language-pack-ja* language-pack-gnome*ja*
```

Changing Windows version to Windows 10 in winecfg

Installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package which comes with `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

and I still get the same issue in foobar2000.

`$LANG` is also set to `en_US.UTF-8`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do not know exactly foobar2000, but I have to start my programs in CP1250 this way:

```
LANG=cs_CZ.UTF-8 wine "/home/xerostomus/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/IDOS2019/TT.exe
```

Then I see our Czech fonts ok. So maybe you have the wrong LANG setting.
But you must be sure that this ORIGINAL CP (not yours) is in your locale:

```
locale -a
```

if not you must add it and refresh:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For foobar2000, there's a few things you need to change:

For the overall program navigate **File > Preferences > Display > Default User Interface > Colors and Fonts > Fonts** and set the **Default** font to a font that supports the Unicode characters you need (such as Arial Unicode MS).

Next, if you're using the properties editor, you need to set the font there too. So navigate to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> **Tools > Fonts** and set the font there.

Finally, if you have Unicode characters in your filesystem, then you need to change the registry. Launch `regedit` and navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Microsoft > Windows NT > CurrentVersion > FontSubstitutes** and change the font for **MS Shell Dig** and **MS Shell Dig2**.

Note that depending on whether you're using other components, you may have to set the font in some of the components' settings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

**File > Preferences > Display > Default User Interface > Colors and Fonts > Fonts** and set the Fonts "AR PL UMing HK", etc.